# ADF Call a bounded taskflow from managed bean

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I need to invoke a bounded task flow from a managed bean.
I am able to call a managed bean method from an event listener in my application.

How do i launch a bounded task flow from the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `TabContext` is Available. Else Pass the Tab context as parameter

```
try {
    TabContext.getCurrentInstance().setTabsRendered(true);
    TabContext.getCurrentInstance().addOrSelectTab("Your Tab Name",
                                                       "/WEB-INF/task-flow-definition.xml#task-flow-definition");
} catch (TabContext.TabOverflowException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Refer: [TaskFlow](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/uishell-093084.html)